# Neo4j Comparing string elements in array to php variable

Tags: php, neo4j

I have nodes in my database that are under the label Keywords with words as an attribute.I would like to compare a string ($mostRecentPost) with the words in the array, words.

```
$queryString ="WITH["Batman","Jaws","Fun","Baseball","Halo","PS4","Nike","Jeep","Mustang"] AS words MATCH (n.Keywords) WHERE ".$mostRecentPost." =~'(?i).*n.kw.*' IN words RETURN n";
$query = new Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query($client, $queryString);
$relativePosts = $query->getResultSet();
```

Basically we have an example $mostRecentPost = a node, with content = "the new Halo looks awesome". I am trying to compare the contents of that node with the contents of the words array, when it matches one of the array words with some word in the post, it returns that word.

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems to be totally off:

1. you don't use your "words" anywhere
2. not sure what `.$mostRecentPost` stands for
3. your regexp is not related to the words at all

   WITH["Batman","Jaws","Fun","Baseball","Halo","PS4","Nike","Jeep","Mustang"] AS words 
   MATCH (n.Keywords) 
   WHERE ".$mostRecentPost." =~'(?i).*n.kw.*' IN words 
   RETURN n

You could do (which will be not fast):

```
MATCH (n:Keywords) 
WHERE n.text =~ '(?i).*(Batman|Jaws|Fun|...).*'
RETURN n
```

**and use a parameter for the regexp-string**

You ***should use fulltext-search*** with a list of words, see this blog post for some info on how to set it up with Neo4j 2.0 http://jexp.de/blog/2014/03/full-text-indexing-fts-in-neo4j-2-0/